# C# Multiple http requests same PHP session

Tags: c#, php, http, httprequest

I'm trying to get the picture to load in the same PHP session in which the POST request will be sent.
But because i'm using button1_Click this is not possible.
And the outcome is to get the picture to load before the data is sent.
If you got any questions please ask.

i know i go wrong with the picture loading, but i dont know exactly where..

using visual c# 2010 express winforms

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://localhost/proj/guess-my-fav/1.jpg";
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/proj/guess-my-fav/level14.php");
        var answer = textBox1.Text;
        string data = "guess=" + answer + "&level=14&time=opt";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        writer.Write(data);
        writer.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        richTextBox1.AppendText(tmp); // log - delete this line          
    }
```

How can i put the rendering of image under the second request?

Comment: I don't think that php and C# should ever overlap like this.

Comment: :)) what do you mean by that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your code to match

```
 private CookieContainer cookieContainer;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/proj/guess-my-fav/1.jpg");
            cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            wr.CookieContainer = this.cookieContainer;
            var resp = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
            wr.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            using (var s = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(s);
            }
        }



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/proj/guess-my-fav/level14.php");
        var answer = textBox1.Text;
        string data = "guess=" + answer + "&level=14&time=opt";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        writer.Write(data);
        writer.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        richTextBox1.AppendText(tmp); // log - delete this line          
    }
```

This should make both requests to the server using the same session.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://localhost/proj/guess-my-fav/1.jpg";
```

This is going to cause the client's browser to make a request for `1.jpg`

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/proj/guess-my-fav/level14.php");
...
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

This is going to cause the webserver running the ASP.NET website to make a request for `level14.php`

You're not going to get those two requests using the same session since they'll be coming from two different machines!

You might like to look into moving that `HttpWebRequest` code out of the back end, and reimplementing it on the client side as an AJAX request. Then both requests will be coming from the client's browser.

Comment: i'd like to avoid the client browser, imma try to render it under the second request

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you want to re-load the image when you click the button.

First of all that `ImageLocation` property is probably not gonna respect your session cookie, so you might have to download the image manually. You already used a `CookieContainer` so that's a good start.

What we want to do here is use a new `HttpWebRequest` to download the image and attach the same `CookieContainer` to it as this one should hold the session id after your first call.
We can then use the `HttpWebResponse` to create an `Image` object and assign this to the `pictureBox1.Image` property.

All this together might look something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/proj/guess-my-fav/level14.php");
    var answer = textBox1.Text;
    string data = "guess=" + answer + "&level=14&time=opt";

    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer(); /* we want to have this for other call also

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(data);
    writer.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
    response.Close();
    richTextBox1.AppendText(tmp); // log - delete this line 

    HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/proj/guess-my-fav/1.jpg");
    request2.CookieContainer = cookies;
    HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.LoadFromStream(response2.GetResponseStream());

}
```